# How to make an almost invisible image on a page that looks okay when zoomed in a lot?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a really really weird question. Is it possible to have something like an image on your page that looks insanely small when browsing normally and you don't even notice it, but when you zoom in a lot, you can clearly see what's there. For example a smiley face that when browsing normally appears as small as a dot, but when you zoom in a lot you can clearly see it. Got this question and honestly I could not answer it, so out of curiosity i decided to ask here. A friend of mine told me that may be possible using SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You could make this effect using SVG, this is [the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGAGyq?editors=0010)!
This animation mainly made using this code:

```
var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.from("svg", 15, {                 // Start the animation from... through 15 seconds!
  scale: 0,                          // Zero scale!
  transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
  ease: Back.easeOut
})

</script>
```

It is a concept! You could make it using any tool (aka SVG)

Answer (score 0):

Well sort of.  Except the problem is that browsers don't really let you zoom a page all that much.  For example, Chrome's max zoom is 500%.  Even if we start with a 5px "dot", zooming by 5x still doesn't let you read the microtext written on that dot.

See the demo below.

Of course I am assuming you meant browser zoom.  But perhaps you meant some other sort of zoom.

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

svg {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    <text x="50" y="55" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" fill="white">Secret text</text>
  </svg>

</div>
```